A question about paying tribute to someone I don't personally know in a paper
Let say person A passed away recently, and I want to pay tribute to A by writing something in the acknowledgement of a paper I am writing. I don't know A personally (having an email conversation doesn't count), but I used to work with the tools A invented for almost all of my papers, and my work is heavily influenced and inspired by the work of A.
My question is: is it strange to write something to pay tribute in the acknowledgement? On one hand, I am not considering writing something like "Dedicated to A" below the title of my paper; what I would write is simply a paragraph saying my work is heavily influenced by the work of A, etc. On the other hand, I don't want to leave an impression to people in my field that the reason of me paying tribute to person A is to have a higher chance for the acceptance of the paper or gain publicity, or anything like these. It is not a must for me to pay tribute to him, but this is something I want to do.
Please let me know what you think. Thank you.

I think it would be fine to include an acknowledgement describing A's importance for your work, as you described it in the question here.

I agree. And you can usually insert or change the acknowledgement section after the peer review. So people won't think you are trying to increase the chance of acceptance.

I’d say acknowledging the influence of someone you admire, or you personally have found influential, can be appropriate and polite.

What you suggest is in essence what we did here: https://www.math.colostate.edu/~bangerth/publications/2022-massive-hp.pdf (see the Acknowledgments, p. 23). I had met Bill Mitchell once or twice, when I was early in my career, but I don't think we conversed more than 30 seconds and I can't say that I "knew" him personally. But I knew of his work and appreciated it.
I tend to think that these kinds of references to the people who do science are actually quite nice. Go with it!
